# Elastic search Index design for logging

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am new to elastic search and trying to use the Elastic search and Kibana to monitor logs of my application. 
I need to monitor three different data queue's parameters(que_in time, que_out time, delay). What should be my index design strategy?
Should I go for a single index and multiple types inside that index for each of three queues or single index with a single type with data of all three queues?
Any other suggestions or pointers, not limited to above case on designing strategy for elastic search index would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/videos/big-data-search-and-analytics/ Found this video interesting.